# Problem for generate a 16x48 datamatrix with iText7

Tags: c#, itext7

I have a problem with this code :

```
BarcodeDataMatrix barreCode = new BarcodeDataMatrix("12345678");
barreCode.SetOptions(BarcodeDataMatrix.DM_EDIFACT);
barreCode.SetWidth(48);
barreCode.SetHeight(16);
PdfFormXObject xobj = barreCode.CreateFormXObject(_pdfDoc);
```

This code throw a System.IndexOutOfRangeException

If I remove the lines

```
barreCode.SetWidth(48);
barreCode.SetHeight(16);
```

it works fine, but i need to generate a datamatrix with these 2 options.

Can anyone help me ?

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide the full stacktrace for the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you should use the constructor without parameters and specify your settings first, and set the code afterwards. Example:

```
BarcodeDataMatrix barcode = new BarcodeDataMatrix();
barcode.SetOptions(BarcodeDataMatrix.DM_EDIFACT);
barcode.SetWidth(48);
barcode.SetHeight(16);
barcode.SetCode("12345678");
```

Comment: Please kindly accept the answer if it helped you :)